# drupal form_execute for repopulation

Tags: drupal

I need a working example of how to repopulate form fields with the help of drupal_execute($form_id,$form_state). I can repopulate by altering the default_values as follows:

```
function sample_myform($form_state){
   $form['field']['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
'#title'=> 'Name: ',
'#maxlength'=> 127,
'#default_value'=> $form_state['values']['name'],
);
$form['field']['button1'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Submit',
);
return $form;
 }

function sample_myform_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
if($form_id=='sample_myform'){
    $id  = db_result(db_query("select max(id) from test2"));
    $name  = db_result(db_query("select name from test2 where id ='$id'"));
    $form['field']['name']['#default_value'] = "$name";
    drupal_set_message(t('Name: '.$name." id: ".$id));
}
  }
```

However, i want to use drupal_execute for repopulation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[drupal_execute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_execute) calls [drupal_prepare_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form) which calls [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter), so you should be fine. On the other hand, you could pass your values in `$form_state['values']` like this:

```
$form_state['values']['name'] =
  db_result(db_query("select name from test2 where id ='$id'"));
drupal_execute('sample_myform', $form_state);
```

However, if [#tree](http://drupal.org/node/48643) is `true` for the element, the first line should read

```
$form_state['values']['field']['name'] =
  db_result(db_query("select name from test2 where id ='$id'"));
```

Comment: @user550265 I just did. Together with your code, this is a full working example.

Comment: Whenever I use drupal_execute(), I get the drupal white screen and my table is filled with 706 rows which have the value which i passed in drupal_execute()   My code is    function sample_myform_submit($form,&$form_state){
 $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
 $result = db_query("insert into test2(name) values ('$name')");
 drupal_set_message(t('value inserted into db is '.$name));
    $form_state['values']['name'] = 'Testing';
 drupal_execute('sample_myform',$form_state);
 $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
}